# Procedure of Converting String to Enum

Tags: jhipster

Since the JHipster doesn't support Enum type in the entity, I have to use the String type in an entity and replace it later. What is a good procedure of such type replacement?

My project is set up with Docker and PostgreSQL for the data repository. The front end is Augarl JS. I have run into some Liquibase errors on JHipster. And it is not fun to correct these errors.

Thanks for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either write your changes as a JHipster module or stop using JHipster. When you start working around its design choices, it's getting too painful to keep in sync manually.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice. I am wondering why the Enum type isn't supported by the current entity yet while JPA/Hibernate has supported Enum type for a long time.

Comment: JHipster uses `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` rather than `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)` because it's more expressive. I suppose that you don't want to use ORDINAL but rather to extend EnumType to map to PostgreSQL enums like in this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), right?

Comment: I was confused by your post. So, I check the JHipster document again. It supports Enum. I guess that it is added recently. I had been away from JHispter for a few of months. I used Enym.STRING Hibernate approach before. I go to create Enum entries.

Comment: Enums were added to entity generator in May 2015 but maybe you refer to an issue from Nov 2017 about enums in JDL https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-core/issues/167

Comment: You are correct. My original question was about an embedded Enum data type in an entity class. (I try to work on JHipster again after a few months absence). I guess that I won't have any choice but create an Enum outside of its related class.